# XSD with Includes to EMF model

Tags: xsd, eclipse-emf

I have some quite big model, described in a number of xsd schemas. Schemas are referencing each other by includes. For example, A schema contains a 'someEnum' enumeration. B schema want to use that enum, so it include's the A schema. The problem is, when i import my XSD to eCore model's EMF are not only generates such an enum twice, but it aslo generates all the elements in B schema in model for A schema. I'm feeling that i'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what exactly. Any help are very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you did select one xsd at a time in the EMF Project Wizard, then you should start with the xsd, that doesn't depend on anything. After the import of the first xsd finished, the EMF Project Explorer offers you to select referenced models during the import of the next xsd. Then you have to select the appropriate ones.

You are also able to import multiple xsds at once with the EMF Project Wizard. Then the references should be set correctly, if the namespaces of the xsds refer to each other.